# Is there any asian company competing with SpaceX?

Tags: china, india

By Asian I mean India, China, Pakistan, Nepal, etc. I wish to know if there is any company which could possibly develop technical know-how and actually launch something to LEO at least on it's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chinese private company (*) [OneSpace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneSpace) launched [its first rocket in 2018](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-space-launch-china-onespace-idUSKCN1II0FK). This vehicle is 9 meters tall and suborbital.

[image]

They're developing several orbital launch vehicle. The first launch of their OS-M, in March 2019, failed.

*: how private this really is remains to be seen.

> Although the company stresses it's privately owned, it does have some links to Chinese authorities.
>
> It says it cooperates with Chinese military institutions on research and development and technical services. The startup also has a manufacturing plant in the southwestern city of Chongqing that is partly owned by the local government.

and

> Xin Zhang, a professor of aerospace engineering at Hong Kong University of Science and Technology, said he doubted the rocket is entirely OneSpace's own work.
>
> The company claimed on Thursday that the rocket it launched only took one year to develop and build. Shu had previously suggested it took three years.

Other countries:

The Japanese space program is state-operated via JAXA, but its rockets are developed and built by commercial companies (Mitsubishi builds the H-IIA). JAXA does the occasional commercial launch. India's ISRO also does commercial missions, but again ISRO is state-operated. Both certainly have 'technical know-how'. JAXA and Mitsubishi don't seem interested in pursuing the low-cost commercial space market, ISRO does compete in the segment SpaceX is in (cheap launches).

I don't see [commercial space companies anywhere else in Asia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Asian_national_space_programs).

Comment: "*: how private this really is remains to be seen" This always seems to be a problem with any company in China, most famous one now being Huawei

Comment: What about this https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2019/05/04/business/tech/momo-3-becomes-first-privately-developed-japanese-rocket-reach-outer-space/#.XSyMoHUzbCI and this https://www.msn.com/en-au/news/techandscience/interstellar-technologies-becomes-first-private-japanese-firm-to-reach-space-with-momo-3-launch/ar-AAAWRxz